# Using a database to save player/team data in a sports sim android app

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to wrap my head around the most efficient way to implement a database in a sports sim game that I'm working on for android.

Currently in the app, the user can pick a team to coach, sim through their schedule, change their lineup, and look up their players' stats as the season goes along. There's no save feature yet so I thought saving all the player stats, team rosters, etc could be implemented with a database.

Right now when a user picks a team, I have a league object that generates all the team objects that in turn have player objects. I'm trying to wrap my head around all of the things I'll have to change in my app with a database. I guess when I generate the league, I'd be doing a lot of writing to the database (teams, players, etc) and then when the user quits and starts up the app again, I'd have to read all that data in and re-create all of the league, team, and player objects? Does that sound like the right way to go about it? I feel like I'm kind of rambling but I don't have much experience at all with using databases with an extremely object oriented app like this.

Comment: If you are comfortable with objects and not databases, look at Realm database

Comment: @cricket_007 Realm looks really intriguing. Do you know how easy it would be to convert my current classes over to "Realm classes"? My classes all have custom methods that do important things for the game. For example, my Team class has a method that randomly generates Player objects and adds them to the Team. Would it be easily compatible with things like that?

Comment: Methods should be okay, but if you have inheritance, then that'll be an issue because you'll need to extend the RealmObject class

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're listing all the teams in all sports all over the world, I think [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/) is suitable to your case.

It's easy to use, debuggable, and lets you prepare/**edit your DB** with tools like SQLite spy, SQLite Database browser or such. Each tool has its good and bad/missing feature, but you'll find great stuff to design and later prepare [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) for your starting database.

If you already wrote objects, **you could both decouple them** with a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) approach to persist teams/rosters/etc., **or choose** to directly make them "persisteable" writing proper methods (ie. refresh(), delete(), etc.) inside classes you already have, [SQLiteQueryBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html) is very useful there.

As a 'pure thumb' order of magnitude, an UPDATE execution of some (3-4) String columns on an average sized (5-10k rows) table **takes milliseconds** (say 5-30ms). For reading, an index based `SELECT *` returns the [SQLiteCursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html) object almost immediately (<5msec.), so that putting pure DML commands can be done even inside Activities' `onCreate()` methods. For "long operations" you mentioned, `AsynchTask` along with proper dialog messages can make the wait less boring and inform the user promptly.

Some limitations could derive from heavy concurrent DB access or later DDL changes (ie. you can't add a FK, you have to drop & recreate table) but the performance on modern devices are great and the **DB file is portable**.

Last not least, the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) is good and many examples are available

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm looking into both SQLite and Realm now. Do you have any experience with Realm?

Comment: no, sorry. I used sqlite on two published app and I'm happy tho

Comment: Hey sorry about the really late comment. I got busy with work for awhile and now I'm starting to look at using sqlite in my sports app again. By making my objects "persistable", do you mean defining methods for writing to the database within the classes themselves? Also, do you think it would be overkill if when the user loads their game, I read from the database and create all of the Team, Player, etc objects in memory?